# Мясо(-)жировое производство?

Tags: орфография

Скажите, как правильно писать "мясожировое производство" или "мясо-жировое производство"?

Comment: Ну прежде всего писать надо с соблюдением орфографических и пунктуационных норм. Если у Вас в вопросе три детских ошибки, то чего вы ждете от ответа?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В специальной литерауре (например, САНИТАРНЫЕ И ВЕТЕРИНАРНЫЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЯ
К ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЮ ПРЕДПРИЯТИЙ МЯСНОЙ ПРОМЫШЛЕННОСТИ) используется слитное написание: **мясожировой**.

Сложные прилагательные подобного вида (первая основа является основой существительного) могут иметь **обе формы написания.**

Можно сравнить: **мясо-молочный и хлебобулочный**. Написание разное, хотя структура слов похожа. Но мясо и молоко связаны между собой косвенным образом, поэтому допускается дефисная форма, а хлебобулочный и мясожировой - это фактически одна тема. Таким образом, семантика основ влияет на выбор формы написания.